# Is it safe to download a site's files and database at the same time?

Tags: wordpress, server, sftp, database-backups, backup-strategies

I am manually downloading a copy of my Wordpress site. I have started by downloading the files via sftp, and as that is progressing I want to download the database from phpMyAdmin.

Is it unwise to perform both of these actions at the same time?

Answer (score 0):

There's really not an issue with doing both at the same time. You're using two different protocols - SFTP and HTTPD (to run PHPMyAdmin) - to get copies of each of the two "parts" of the site, the static files and the database.

The static site files are just files (php, html, images, etc), while the database is data in a separate application layer than the SFTP server or the webserver (Apache, NginX, etc) itself.

As long as your web host can handle the loads at the same time from both SFTP for files and the CPU usage and PHP timeout parameters to export what could be a large database, there's no issue. If you do get PHP timeouts or errors exporting the database, you will need to increase PHP timeouts, PHP maximum post sizes, etc., in order to export the database.